# compress text in java if it gets too long

Tags: java, text, textfield, java-canvas

i want to add print functionality to my software, this requires to compress the text not fit them in the textbox (letters should not be shrunk vertically).

is this possible with standard java methods or does someboday know good extensions?

i want to have the text like on the attached picture

Thanks![image]

Comment: you could try and change the fontsize

Comment: "letters should not be shrunk" do you mean vertical, but can be shrunk horizontally.

Comment: yes, exactly! The text-size should not get any smaller but can shrink horizontally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to override `paintComponent()` and apply horizontal scale to the `Graphics` instance

```
Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)g;
AffineTransform old=g2d.getTransform();
g2d.scale(0.5, 1);
//paint the text here
g2d.setTransform(old);
```